# How to stop item trembling on recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a notification center using a 
recyclerview displayed on a fragment , when I click on the item it writes a value on the database and then base of the condition the green Notification Bell appears/dissapears, the problem here is that all items get affected from trembling effect

Image:
https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-1adb4a5b29e3.gif

My adapter

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
NotifsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(currentUserID).child("comments").child(delUid).hasChild("state"))
                {
                    String state = dataSnapshot.child(currentUserID).child("comments").child(delUid).child("state").getValue().toString();
                    if (state.equals("unread"))
                    {
                        holder.notifImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else {
                        holder.notifImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }}}
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {         NotifsRef.child(currentUserID).child("comments").child(delUid).child("state").setValue("read");              
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNotifications.size();
    }
```

Fragment:

```
{
OnCreate{...}

notificationList = (RecyclerView) notificationFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.notifications_list);

        notificationAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(getContext(), mNotifications);
        notificationList.setAdapter(notificationAdapter);
        notificationList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        notificationList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
}

private void readMsgList()
    {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            { mNotifications.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.child(currentUserID).child("comments").getChildren())
                {
                    Notifications notifications = snapshot.getValue(Notifications.class);
                        mNotifications.add(notifications);
                }
                notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
}});
    }
```

I have tried to change the listener from ValueEventListener to SingleValueEventListener but without any result.
Is there any way to correct this ?